# Why date pipe doesn't work properly with ng2-bootstrap in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I want to show date in next format: `dd/MM/yyyy`, but it only shows in `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Here is my `startdateComponent`:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Output, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker';

@Component({
templateUrl:'./app/home/item_component/start_date_component/start_date_component.html',
directives: [DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class StartDateComponent () {
chosenDate : Date =  new Date();

getDate() {
    return this.chosenDate;
 }  
}
```

Template is:

```
 <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 datePicked ">
   <span>
     <h4>{{getDate() | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h4>
   </span>
 </div>
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question.  Here is the answer, [from the source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ae75e3640a2d9eb1e897a0771d92b976c5a42c75/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts):

```
* ## Usage
 *
 *     expression | date[:format]
 *
 * where `expression` is a date object or a number (milliseconds
 *  since UTC epoch) or an ISO string
 * (https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) and `format` indicates which
 *  date/time components to
 * include:
 ...
 * In javascript, only the components specified will be respected 
 *  (not the ordering,
 * punctuations, ...) and details of the formatting will be dependent
 *  on the locale.
```

So the answer is, "because `format` does not work the way you expect it to work."

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on new ng2-bootstrap datepicker and will expose moment.js powered date format, so you can use any format from: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

PS if you want to get it asap and get updates, join https://www.hamsterpad.com/chat/ng2