# Angular2 - Issue with Date pipe

Tags: angular

I am trying to format the date time that I fetch from the DB in the following format:

> 15/09/2016, 20:45

However using the default `date` Pipe provided by Angular2, I get the following (***When I run on a real device***) *However, On the browser it shows the correct* format:

> 15/09/2016, 20:8:45 PM

Here is how I am formatting it in the HTML side:

```
{{ order.time | date:"dd/MM/y, HH:mm" }}
```

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: When you fetch date, do you get it in string type or date type?

Comment: @micronyks Date type

Comment: @micronyks what do you mean by date type? in JSON it will be in string format only right?

Comment: @HamzaL. [See my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38352762/1375316).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. You have to make sure that date which you fetch must be in date format. If it is, it will work properly with **date pipe**. If it is not you have to make sure that you convert it in to date as shown below. (This may help you to understand what I mean)

**Working Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/aaFu5G759ghUQvk1a9Zw**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `      
  {{date|date:"dd/MM/y, HH:mm"}} //<----- here make sure date variable has proper date(type)
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 

  date=new Date(2016,08,5,20,45);   

  //<---- date variable gets proper date(type)
  //<---- also note month starts with zero(0) so for sep month (08) is taken.
}
```

Comment: The issue with your answer is that at the controller level I don't have the `date` variable as it's generated with an ngFor on the view level. Furthermore, the date object is received from the DB in the following format: `2016-09-15T19:45:00.000Z`

Comment: Thats fine. I just gave  you some hint. Whatever you have, you just need to make sure that you deal with date type at the end. Then n then it will work the way you want.

Comment: I can't make it work, especially because the received format from the DB is `2016-09-15T19:45:00.000Z`

Comment: You can easily conver it in to date format. Just google it little bit and you will be able to resolve your issue.

Comment: Not sure but i think its(which one you just showed) call ed `timestamp  format`.  Now search how to convert it in to proper desire date.

Comment: @HamzaL. I'd say this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681078/angular-2-date-deserialization